# Detect ELMAH exceptions during integration (WATIN + NUNIT) tests

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, watin, elmah

Here is my scenario:

- I have a suite of WATIN GUI tests that run against a ASP.net MVC3 web app per build in CI. The tests verify that the GUI behaves as expected when given certain inputs.
- The web app uses ELMAH xml files for logging exceptions.

Question: How can I verify that no unexpected exceptions occurred during each test run. It would also be nice to provide a link to the ELMAH detail of the exception in the NUNIT output if an exception did occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what my tests do:

1. During test setup record the time
2. Run test
3. During test teardown browse to (elmah.axd/download) and parse the ELMAH CSV
4. Filter out rows that don't match the user that is running the WATIN tests and rows where the UNIX time was before the recorded time in (1)
5. If there are rows report the exception message and the error URL to NUNIT.

Seems to work well, we have already caught a couple of bugs that wouldn't have surfaced until a human tested the app.

Answer (score 1):

Elmah runs in the web application which is a separate process from the test runner. There is no easy way to directly intercept unhandled errors. 
The first thing that comes to mind is to watch the folder (App_Data?) that holds the Elmah XML error reports.

You could clear error reports from the folder when each test starts and check whether it is still empty at the end of the test. If the folder is not empty you can copy the error report(s) into the test output.

This approach is not bullet proof. It could happen that an error has occurred but the XML file was not yet (completely) written when you check the folder. For example when your web application is timing out. You could potentially also run into file locking issues if you try to read an XML file that is still being written.

Instead of reading XML files from disk you could configure Elmah to log to a database and read the error reports from there. That would help you get around file locking issues if they occur.

Comment: I tried the watch the app_data folder idea that Marnix van Valen suggested, but as identified you can't always be sure that an xml file has been written when an exception occurs. I think ELMAH sometimes holds the exception data in memory until one browses to the AXD and the specific exception. SQL is out because we'd like to avoid the dependency. Another route I am going to try is downloading and parsing the CSV log that ELMAH provides. Will post with results. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not go to the Elmah reporting view (probably elmah.axd) in the setup of your WatiN test and read the timestamp of the most recent error logged there.  Then do the same after your test and assert that the timestamps are the same.

It would be easy to read the url of this most recent error from the same row and record that in the message of your failing assert which would then be in your nunit output.

Comment: The time column in the reporting view (elmah.axd) only goes to the minute. The CSV of the log (elmah.axd/download) has a UNIX time column which I ended up using to get the time accuracy I needed.